# destroy-method not invoked on beans registered as prototype

Tags: spring

I have a bean registered as singleton and init-method and destroy-method defined on it. I am accessing the bean and can see the calls being made to both the methods. However, on changing the scope to prototype the destroy-method is not invoked.

I am not getting the rationale behind this.

Comment: Has a very good example how these methods work here: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-init-method-and-destroy-method-example/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-prototype):

> In contrast to the other scopes, Spring does not manage the complete lifecycle of a prototype bean: the container instantiates, configures, and otherwise assembles a prototype object, and hands it to the client, with no further record of that prototype instance. Thus, although initialization lifecycle callback methods are called on all objects regardless of scope, in the case of prototypes, configured destruction lifecycle callbacks are not called.

And that's quite logical: your application could ask for new instances of prototype beans every 10 milliseconds, do something with the bean, and then let it go out of scope. If Spring had to destroy() them when the application shuts down, it would have to keep a reference to every created prototype bean, preventing them to be garbage-collected, and thus causing a memory leak.

Comment: I thought that the responsibility to destroy a prototyped bean lay with the application with a risk of memory leak if the programmer omitted the explicit destruction of the prototyped bean from memory.  JB-Nizet : are you suggesting that this is not the case and that prototyped beans will get garbage-collected?